# How to kill a Windows subprocess in Python when it expects a key but simply doesn't react to it through stdin?

Tags: python, c, windows, subprocess, stdin

I am trying to kill a subprocess that expects a key press 'q' in the terminal in order to stop gracefully.

This executable has two modes of running (tried both):

- takes over the terminal with probably some sort of ncurses (considering it is Windows it is probably something else)
- just runs in the terminal as a regular command and waits for a key press

I have tried spawning the subprocess with `subprocess.Popen(command_parts)` where `command_parts` is a list with the executable and it's various flags.

I have added the following arguments to the Popen constructor in multiple combinations:

- no special flags
- with `creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS`
- with `stdin=PIPE`

I have tried sending to the stdin of the executable the following strings:

- `b"q"`
- `b"q\n"`
- `b"q\r\n"`

I have tried communicating with the executable in the following ways:

- `subprocess_instance.communicate(input_stuff)`
- `subprocess_instance.stdin.write(input_stuff); subprocess_instance.stdin.flush()`

None of these attempts results in the executable gracefully shutting down, and just lingers forever as if nothing happened on the stdin.

Observations:

- the q keystroke works if simply running the executable from power shell
- the executable has to close gracefully otherwise it results in some undesired behaviour
- Python versions used: 3.8.*, 3.9.*

UPDATE:

I tried using a sample C program that waits for 'q':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  printf("Hello world\n");

  printf("Waiting for char ...\n");

  while (1) {
    unsigned int x = getch();
    printf("PRESSED: %c\n", x);
    if (x == 'q') {
      printf("Quitting ...\r\n");
      break;
    };
  }

  printf("\n----\n");
  printf("DONE\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

And then the script I tried to use to run it is:

```py
import time
import subprocess as sp
import pathlib as plib


def main() -> None:
    print("\nSTARTING")

    print("Create subproces ...");
    exe_path = plib.Path('guinea_pig_executable/bla.exe').absolute()
    exe_path_str = str(exe_path)
    exe = sp.Popen(
        [exe_path_str],
        stdin=sp.PIPE,
        stdout=sp.PIPE,
        stderr=sp.PIPE,
    )

    print("Wait ...")
    time.sleep(5)

    print("Try quitting ...")
    try:
        exe.communicate(b'q\r\n', timeout=2)
        # exe.stdin.write(b'q')
        # exe.stdin.flush()
    except Exception as err:
        print(repr(err))

    print("Wait for sub proc to die ...")
    try:
        exe.wait(timeout=5)
    except sp.TimeoutExpired as terr:
        print("Timeout error", repr(terr))
        exe.kill()  # forcefully killing

    print("\nEND\n---\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output I get is:

```sh
PS E:\workspace\try-kill-exe> python .\main.py

STARTING
Create subproces ...
Wait ...
Try quitting ...
TimeoutExpired(['E:\\workspace\\try-kill-exe\\guinea_pig_executable\\bla.exe'], 2)
Wait for sub proc to die ...
Timeout error TimeoutExpired(['E:\\workspace\\try-kill-exe\\guinea_pig_executable\\bla.exe'], 5)

END
---
```

What could be the cause for this? Is this something windows specific? Is it something that Python can't handle properly? What other things could I try?

Comment: If the executable is waiting for a key press, it's quite likely not reading it from `stdin`. The Windows runtime provides ways to check for physical key presses. See [`msvcrt.kbhit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-oP).

Comment: @john-hen, @martineau I made a fake C program that would wait for 'q' and it behaves similarly to the vendor specific exe. Also posted a sample of the Python script.

@john-hen I tried with `text=True` as well, but same result. 

I think @martineau might be on to something when he said that it might not read it from stdin. I see that even though it starts in a different subprocess, it still reacts to any keypresses in the main terminal, which is absolutely peculiar. I will try with some windows-specific libraries and maybe even in a `multiprocessing.Process` instance.

Comment: The solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8117562) works for your sample program as well.

Comment: @john-hen nailed it. I found out it works with pynput as well. I guess the key is communicating with the "Windows Client API" aka "user32.dll"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which a python script can communicate with a subprocess when it comes to keypresses.

- pywin32
- pynput
- pyautogui
- ctypes + `user32.dll`

## Examples

### PyWin32

(credits to @john-hen -> inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8117562/858565)

Package: https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/

```py
import win32console


def make_keydown_input(c):
    input_record = win32console.PyINPUT_RECORDType(win32console.KEY_EVENT)
    input_record.KeyDown = 1
    input_record.RepeatCount = 1
    input_record.Char = c
    return input_record

console_handler = win32console.GetStdHandle(win32console.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)

q_keydown = make_keydown_input('q')
console_handler.WriteConsoleInput([q_keydown])
```

### pynput

Package: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

```py
import pynput

keyb_controller = pynput.keyboard.Controller()

keyb_controller.press('q')
```

### pyautogui

Package: https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

Examples: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

This is probably the simplest method.

```py
import pyautogui

pyautogui.press('q')
```

### ctypes + `user32.dll`

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13615802/858565

In the end you just have to call:

```py
PressKey(0x51)
```

where `0x51` is the hex keycode for `q` according to (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)

## Observations

Notice that all of these methods will apply the keypress in the context of the program that calls it. I have not tried it with multiprocessing.Process, perhaps it will react differently.

Probably to have a good isolated context one would have to run a specific subprocess in an isolated python script that simply receives messages from outside like via a socket.

Comment: Do one or all of these answer your question? Also, in the first snippet, since `make_keydown_input()` returns `None`, why are you assigning its return value to `q_keydown` and then using that value? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @martineau ah yes misleading type hint, removing. Yes all of those versions handle key press events in Windows.